# Should I use archive page or page template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, performance, wordpress-theming

I have custom post type by the name stocks

Now I have two options to show all the stocks.

First is to create a page template and get all the stocks using get_posts.

Second is to create archive-stocks.php according to WordPress template hierarchy

I was thinking which one would be a better option to do in terms of performance,speed, seo etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in comparing the performance of archive pages VS page templates, then a lot will depend on how exactly you write your page template query.

To render the archive page for all posts of type 'stocks', I personally would make use of the WordPress template hierarchy and use `archive-{post_type}.php` (in your case this would be `archive-stocks.php`).

To render a single post of type 'stocks' I would use `single-{post_type}.php` (in your case this would be `single-stocks.php`).

**Ref:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You should use archive page - in your case `archive-stocks.php`
It is considered the right way to use the template hierarchy in this case.

Comment: Me too trying to select the best way of doing so. Do you have any resources in support of using archive instead of page templates.

Comment: Archive templates are for displaying a list of all posts. A page template should be for single display (i.e. if you clicked on a post). You would use `single-stocks.php` for a single output.